# anonymous innerclass of interface type accesses 'overrided' fields

Tags: java, interface, anonymous-inner-class

Why does an anonymous inner class constructed from an interface return data from the interface when the same data is redefined in the anonymous inner class definition.  Please take a look at this code, where it appears that the fields in the interface and the anonymous class, with the same name get accessed:

```
interface Item{
  int data=0;
  String text="";
}
public class Problem2{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Item item=new Item(){ public int data=2; public String text="an item";
                            public boolean equals(Object object){
                              if(object instanceof Item){
                                Item test=(Item)object; //tests on next line
                                System.out.println(test); System.out.println(String.format("data: %d; text: \"%s\"", test.data, test.text)); //returns data and text fields of interface, after returning fields defined in anonymous class on toString call
                                System.out.println(test); //toString returns same
                                return data==test.data && text.equals(test.text); } return false;} 
                            public String toString(){return String.format("{data: %d; text: \"%s\"}", data, text);} };

    System.out.println(((Object)item).equals(item)); //returns false
  }
}
```

Please explain how it returns the field of the interface while the fields of the anonymous inner class does not change.
Output:

```
{data: 2; text: "an item"}
data: 0; text: ""
{data: 2; text: "an item"}
false
```

Comment: Okay, I see,  So this is to say that the Item interface argument that gets passed in is expected to be immutable... and therefore the item.data and item.text is seen as final, as specified in the interface implicitly.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is abstract classes, not interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in java you **cannot** override variables

you only override methods

and here while creating the anon class when you type test.data it will refer to the interface data not the local variable (local variable accessible using this.data or data directly) since you issued the .data on an object of the interface type.

to resolve you issue just use getter methods

here is full example

```
interface Item{
    int data=0;
    String text="";
public int getData();
public String getText();

}
public class Test12{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Item item=new Item(){ public int data=2; public String text="an item";
            public int getData(){
                return data;
            }
            public String getText(){
                return text;
            }
            public boolean equals(Object object){
                if(object instanceof Item){
                    Item test=(Item)object; //tests on next line
                    System.out.println(test); System.out.println(String.format("data: %d; text: \"%s\"", test.getData(), test.getData())); //returns data and text fields of interface, after returning fields defined in anonymous class on toString call
                    System.out.println(test); //toString returns same
                    return data==test.getData() && text.equals(test.getText()); } return false;}
            public String toString(){return String.format("{data: %d; text: \"%s\"}", data, text);} };

        System.out.println(((Object)item).equals(item)); //returns false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables aren't getting overriden, you are referring 2 diff set of variables, , the ones in the interface are always `public static final`, which means basically constants, the the anonymous definition is not. Based on how you refer to them, the output changes.

Comment: This is what I see as well.  But the same thing happens with classes as well.... When I reference item.data or item.text it shows the default values from the class defintion, even when I overrided them in the anonymous inner class.  Class members are not final.

Comment: @DannyP. You are not overriding the variables in the interface,  as the variables declared in the interface are by default final, they can't be overridden, not to mention static, which means they are not state variables, unlike your anonymous class.